# Actualizar campos de una BDD en Sqlite desde un modelo en Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Tengo los siguientes modelos

```
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(length = 30), nullable= False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(length= 40), nullable= False, unique= True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(length=60), nullable = False)
    budget = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable= False, default= 1000)
    items = db.relationship('Item', backref='owned_user', lazy=True)


class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length= 30),nullable=False, unique=True)
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(length=12), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(length=1024), nullable=False, unique=True)
    owner = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

sin embargo agregue despues la clave, el budget, items y owner despues y en DB browser sqlite solo me aparecen los campos los demas campos sin los que mencione arriba, como hago para actualizarlos? ya que me esta generando problemas a la hora de crear objetos de los modelos

este es el error que me sale:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError:
 Foreign key associated with column 'item.owner' could not find table 'user' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando el método create_all() para crear las tablas, no?

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables

Creo que deberías hacer un drop y luego el create para recrear las tablas nuevamente.

De todas formas, lo mas recomendable es usar migraciones para este tipo de cosas: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#altering-database-objects-through-migrations

Una muy buena alternativa para esto es usar [Alemic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)